# Objects retrieved from observable JSON don't have methods defined in class

Tags: class, angular, observable

Service:

```
getGroups():Observable<Group[]> {

    return this._http.get(this.url).map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

Class:

```
export class Group {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    vat: string;

    items: Item[];

    addItem = function(item: Item): void{
        this.items.push(item);
    }
}
```

Component:

```
groups:Group[];
selectedGroup:Group;

onSelectGroup(currentGroup:Group):void {
    this.selectedGroup = currentGroup;
}

ngOnInit():void {

    this.groupService.getGroups().subscribe(groups => this.groups = groups);

}
```

Template:

```
    <div *ngFor="let g of groups" [class.selected]="g === selectedGroup">

                    <button (click)="onSelectGroup(g)">Select group</button>

</div>
```

When I try to use the method (on a single array element - group of course) addItem(ItemObject) it says "this.selectedGroup.addItem is not a function".

Help please

Comment: the rest of properties I can get without problems. The only thing I lose is the method.. why?

Comment: where is your `selectedGroup` defined ? show more code please

Comment: Because you haven't actually converted the JSON to that object.

Comment: return this._http.get(this.url).map((res: Response) => res.json() as Group); - this does not help;

return this._http.get(this.url).map((res: Response) => res.json() as Group[]); - this neither

Comment: Casting to a type doesn't change anything. You just tell the tools (IDE) that statically analyze your code that it's safe to assume this value is of type `Group` but is just ignored at runtime (as all type information is)